What to make of どうなっても in this sentence?

半ば強引にききだしてしったんだ
心臓に持病があること
大きな発作が来たらどうなってもおかしくないこと

So the character mentions how he asked a girl what was up with her acting weird. Thus the narration explains that's how he learned several things about her.
One thing he learned is that she had a heart condition
"心臓に持病があること"
However, what to make of this line?
大きな発作が来たらどうなってもおかしくないこと
"If a large spasm comes.... it wouldn't be weird"
I can't quite make sense of どうなっても "No matter what happens"?

It's best to look at “〜てもおかしくない” as a set phrase meaning something like “It's plausible that ...” or “I wouldn't be surprised if ...”. Literally it means “It wouldn't be strange if ...” but it's a very common expression to simply remark that something could reasonably happen. “このままじゃ死んでもおかしくないよ！” means something like “You might very well at this rate man!”
In this case with “どう” in it “どうなってもおかしくない” just means “anything could happen.” basically. You may not know this but interrogative words such as “どう" or “どこ” can combine with the “〜ても” form or other similar forms to mean something like “-ever” in English, as in “どう考えても” means “However you think about it.” or “どこにいようと”　means “wherever [he] is”. So literally we get “However it might end up, it wouldn't be strange.” but look at it like “Anything could happen.” So:

Really, anything could happen if she were to have a big spasm.

Also, finally “どうなる” and “そうなる" and such often talk about what will happen as in “どうなるかはわからないけど” while literally meaning “I don't know what it will become though.” more so means “I don't know what will happen though.”

There seems to be a typo in your translation – you've written "have big a spasm" rather than "have a big spasm." Also, any particular reason why you're following the OP in translating 発作 (which usually means "attack" or "episode," in the medical sense) as "spasm" (which is more like 痙攣)?

@Nanigashi no real reason; I just followed it without thinking I guess. To me “spasm” feels like a more informal term to say “seizure”.

Hmm. In modern American English, "spasm" really isn't a less formal word for "seizure"; it's simply a different word, for a different thing. Might be different in British English or other dialects, though. (Fine answer overall, in any case.)
